# Lambda function taking >3 seconds to run + 5-10 secs warmup each time

Tags: node.js, json, rest, sockets, aws-lambda

I have a simple node.js function with 2 REST API calls and a socket connection output hosted in an AWS lambda. It takes 5-10 secs warmup time and >3+ secs execution time.

When the code is run locally it executes both requests, socket connection and completes in about ~1300ms. Why is AWS more then double the execution time? I have set-timeout to 120seconds and memory at 128mb (default).

I appreciate the code is not very tidy; I am working on cleaning it but needed something going for the time being.

The project simply gets info from ServiceM8 via API when called by a webhook subscription, then formats the info into ZPL strings and forwards them to a tcp server for printing via thermal printer.

My questions are:

1. Is it my code bottle necking?
2. Can it be optimized to run faster?
3. Do i simply need to employ a warming plugin for my function to allow hot starting?

My function:

```
'use strict';
//Require libraries
var request = require("request");
var net = require('net');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    if (event.eventName != 'webhook_subscription') { 
        callback(null, {});
    }


    //Global Variables
    var strAssetUUID;
    var strAssetURL;
    var strFormUUID;
    var strTestDate;
    var strRetestDate;
    var appliancePass = true;
    var strAccessToken;
    var strResponseUUID;

    //Printer Access
    const tcpUrl = 'example.com';
    const tcpPort = 12345;
    var client = new net.Socket();

    //UUID of Appliance Test Form.
    const strTestFormUUID = 'UUID_of_form';

//Begin function

    /**
     * Inspect the `eventArgs.entry` argument to get details of the change that caused the webhook
     * to fire.
     */
    strResponseUUID = event.eventArgs.entry[0].uuid;
    strAccessToken = event.auth.accessToken;

    console.log('Response UUID: ' + strResponseUUID);
    console.log('Access Token: ' + strAccessToken);

    //URL Options for FormResponse UUID query
    const urlFormResponse = {  
        url: 'https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/formresponse.json?%24filter=uuid%20eq%20' + strResponseUUID,
        headers: {
            // Use the temporary Access Token that was issued for this event
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + strAccessToken
        }
    };

//Query form Response UUID to get information required.
request.get(urlFormResponse, function(err, res, body) {
    //Check response code from API query
    if (res.statusCode != 200) {
        // Unable to query form response records
        callback(null, {err: "Unable to query form response records, received HTTP " + res.statusCode + "\n\n" + body});
        return;
        }
    //If we do recieve a 200 status code, begin 
    var arrRecords = JSON.parse(body);

    //Store the UUID of the form used for the form response.
    strFormUUID = arrRecords[0].form_uuid;
    console.log('Form UUID: ' + strFormUUID);

    //Store the UUID of the asset the form response relates to.
    strAssetUUID = arrRecords[0].asset_uuid;
    console.log('Asset UUID: ' + strAssetUUID);

    if (strFormUUID == strTestFormUUID){
            //Get the edited date and parse it into a JSON date object.
            var strEditDate = new Date(arrRecords[0].edit_date);
            //Reassemble JSON date to dd-mm-yyyy.
            strTestDate = strEditDate.getDate() + '/' + (strEditDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + strEditDate.getFullYear();
            //Extract the response for retest period.
            var strRetestAnswer = JSON.parse(arrRecords[0].field_data);
            strRetestAnswer = strRetestAnswer[0].Response;
            //Appropriate function based on retest response.
            switch(strRetestAnswer) {
                case '3 Months':
                    //Add x months to current test date object
                    strEditDate.setMonth(strEditDate.getMonth() + 3);
                    strRetestDate = strEditDate.getDate() + '/' + (strEditDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + strEditDate.getFullYear();
                    break;
                case '6 Months':
                    strEditDate.setMonth(strEditDate.getMonth() + 6);
                    strRetestDate = strEditDate.getDate() + '/' + (strEditDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + strEditDate.getFullYear();
                    break;
                case '12 Months':
                    strEditDate.setMonth(strEditDate.getMonth() + 12);
                    strRetestDate = strEditDate.getDate() + '/' + (strEditDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + strEditDate.getFullYear();
                    break;
                case '2 Years':
                    strEditDate.setMonth(strEditDate.getMonth() + 24);
                    strRetestDate = strEditDate.getDate() + '/' + (strEditDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + strEditDate.getFullYear();
                    break;
                case '5 Years':
                    strEditDate.setMonth(strEditDate.getMonth() + 60);
                    strRetestDate = strEditDate.getDate() + '/' + (strEditDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + strEditDate.getFullYear();
                    break;
                default:
                    strRetestDate = "FAIL";
                    appliancePass = false;
            }

            console.log('Appliance Pass: ' + appliancePass);
            console.log('Test Date: ' + strTestDate);
            console.log('Retest Period: ' + strRetestAnswer);
            console.log('Retest Date: ' + strRetestDate);

            //URL Options for Asset UUID query
            const urlAssetResponse = {
            url: 'https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/asset/' + strAssetUUID + '.json',
            headers: {
                // Use the temporary Access Token that was issued for this event
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + strAccessToken
                }
            };

            //Query the api for the asset URL of the provided asset UUID.
            request.get(urlAssetResponse, function(err, res, body) {
                //Check response code from API query
                if (res.statusCode != 200) {
                    // Unable to query asset records
                    callback(null, {err: "Unable to query asset records, received HTTP " + res.statusCode + "\n\n" + body});
                    return;
                }
                //If we do recieve a 200 status code, begin 
                var strAssetResponse = JSON.parse(body);
                //Store the asset URL
                strAssetURL = 'https://sm8.io/' + strAssetResponse.asset_code;
                console.log('Asset URL: ' + strAssetURL);
            //generate tag and send to printer
            var strZPLPass = ('^XA....^XZ\n');
            var strZPLFail = ('^XA....^XZ\n');
                            //Now that we have our ZPL generated from our dates and URLs
                            //Send the correct ZPL to the printer.
                            client.connect(tcpPort, tcpUrl, function() {
                                console.log('Connected');
                                //Send Appropriate ZPL
                                if (appliancePass) {
                                    client.write(strZPLPass);
                                }else {
                                    client.write(strZPLFail);
                                }
                                console.log('Tag Successfully Printed!');
                                //As the tcp server receiving the string does not return any communication
                                //there is no way to know when the data has been succesfully received in full.
                                //So we simply timeout the connection after 750ms which is generally long enough
                                //to ensure complete transmission.
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    console.log('Timeout, connection closing...');
                                    client.destroy();
                                    }, 750);
                                });
            });
    }
});
};
```

Comment: Have you tried running it with more provisioned memory? How does the performance change in that case?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would suggest you stop using the `request` module and switch to native. Everything can be done without a tons of lines these days. `request` is a module with 48 total dependencies; if you do the math, that's thousands of lines for a simple GET request.

You should always minimize the complexity of your dependencies. I use a Lambda to check the health of my sites, grabbing the whole request and checking the HTML on **completely different servers**. VPS is located in Frankfurt, AWS in Ireland. My ms/request is ranging between 100~150 ms.

Here's a simple promise request I'm using:

```
function request(obj, timeout) {
    return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
        if (typeof obj !== "object") {
            rej("Argument must be a valid http request options object")
        }
        obj.timeout = timeout;
        obj.rejectUnauthorized = false;
        let request = http.get(obj, (response) => {
            if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
                rej("Connection error");
            }
            var body = '';
            response.on('data', (chunk) => {
                body += chunk;
            });
            response.on('end', () => {
                res(body);
            });
            response.on('error', (error) => {
                rej(error);
            });
        });

        request.setTimeout(timeout);
        request.on('error', (error) => {
            rej(error);
        })
        request.on('timeout', () => {
            request.abort();
            rej("Timeout!")
        })
    });
}
```

Example

```
const reqOpts = {
    hostname: 'www.example.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/hello',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        handshake: "eXTNxFMxQL4pRrj6JfzQycn3obHL",
        remoteIpAddress: event.sourceIp || "lambda"
    }
}
try {
    httpTestCall = await request(reqOpts, 250);
}
catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

Now based on that change switch your handler to async using `exports.handler = async(event, context, callback) => {}` and use console to measure the execution time of every request using `console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()` for your request or anything. From there you could see what's stepping down your code using Cloudwatch logs. Here's another example based on your code:

```
let reqOpts = {
  hostname: 'api.servicem8.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/api_1.0/formresponse.json?%24filter=uuid%20eq%20' + strResponseUUID,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    // Use the temporary Access Token that was issued for this event
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + strAccessToken
}
}

console.time("=========MEASURE_servicem8=========")
let error = null;
await request(reqOpts, 5555).catch((e)=>{
  error = e;
})
console.timerEnd("=========MEASURE_servicem8=========")
if (error){
  callback(null, {err: "Unable to query form response records, received HTTP" + error}); /* or anything similar */ 
}
```

References
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html

Comment: First of all, really appreciate such a detailed response. Thank you. Secondly, I was blissfully unaware of the quantity of dependencies that request contains. Wow.

I will rebuild my code with your example and report back when I have tested it. My only other concern is, would there be any benefit to changing to async handler as this script is only called once at a time, several minutes apart, and each request inside the script is dependent on values pulled from the previous request so I can't run them simultaneously. <= I may be misunderstand the async though.

Comment: @Jasonson What do you mean? If you execute a Lambda function 10 times, AWS will spawn 10 different containers, so basically you can't store values anywhere in your app or anything. Now, if you just don't want to switch to async you can just "chain" your promises like the following example: `request(args_here).then((res,rej)=>{ 

code_here
request(args_here).then((res,rej)=>{
code_here
})  })`

Comment: I must have implemented your code incorrectly as now my function does nothing at all. After changing to your code and changing to async, I cannot even log to the console, the data sent to function by servicem8 ```event.eventArgs.entry[0].uuid```

Comment: @Jasonson That's weird, are you using the latest Node.js version?

Answer (score -1):

aws lambdas are not fast by nature (as of writing this answer). The startup time is not guaranteed, and it is known to be high.

If you need performance - you will not get it this way.

Comment: That sucks. The function is hosted on the same server us-west-1 as servicem8 so I assumed the requests would run at a decent pace. All the info I can find says that if I hit the lambda often enough it will stay hot and avoid the cold start times. However my real-world use case would hit it once every 3-4 minutes. I might look into a warming plugin to keep my function hot.

Comment: Or making this function a standard API into your server. You will also gain the ability to debug the code being run by your ... "function".

Comment: I currently don't have a server. That is why I hosted the function on aws. I am looking into building a basic node server with this function on a raspberry pi.

Comment: You will not get a good performance from that. If you are learning, ok. But otherwise - using a real server is a good idea. DigitalOcean are quite cheap, you might want to look at them.